# How can I obtain a window handle in SDL 2.0.3?

Tags: sdl2

I need to obtain the handle of the window for SDL 2.0.3. I got the suggestion to use `info.window` after initializing SDL and filling the info variable with data by calling `SDL_GetWindowWMInfo();` included in the header file `SDL_syswm.h`. My compiler (Visual Studio 2008) gives the following error:

> 226) : error C2039: 'window' : is not a member of 'SDL_SysWMinfo'
>   1>     include\sdl_syswm.h(173) : see declaration of 'SDL_SysWMinfo'

Comment: Yep, that's what I was going to say. According to the [documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SysWMinfo) it is `info.win.window`.

Comment: Feel free to add a proper answer (either of you) and mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 7):

Getting the window handle from an SDL window is pretty straightforward:

```
SDL_SysWMinfo systemInfo; 
SDL_VERSION(&systemInfo.version);
SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(window, &systemInfo);

HWND handle = systemInfo.info.win.window;
```